# What is the right Data Type for postal Code?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Thank you in advance. I need this for our Thesis that will be Defended on August. Please

Comment: You should give more context. A universal postal code? A US/European/... one?

Comment: A Philippine Postal Code Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

The right data type for a postal code is a string.  In a SQL database, this would typically be `VARCHAR()` or `CHAR()`, of the appropriate length.

A numeric data type is *not* appropriate even if the values look like a number.  Here is one simple reason:  you cannot perform arithmetic on them.  In addition, leading zeros are important.